# Provision with Vagrant on a box that uses Busybox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, busybox, ash, mesh-network

When I try provisioning on my Freifunk gluon node like I do it on my other debian machines:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "bootstrap-node.sh"
end
```

Then I get the error:

```
The configured shell (config.ssh.shell) is invalid and unable
```

How do I configure provisioning for Busybox `ash`?

Comment: Funny message! :) Does your busy box include `bash`? If not, are you able to include it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My busybox doesn't include bash, It is made for a small router with ust 4MB ram.

You can configure it with

```
config.ssh.shell = 'ash'
```

This will define ash as shell. See: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html

This is the solution for my question here, though I now have a follow-up problem, which is another question: [vagrant ash: sudo: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173472/vagrant-ash-sudo-not-found)

Comment: I found out this solution, I can accept it tomorrow

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure and it is hard to reproduce.