# vagrant ash: sudo: not found

Tags: vagrant, busybox

When starting my vagrant box with a small 15MB Busybox image, the first time I get an error during the phase

```
Mounting shared folders...
```

It seems vagrant is trying something with sudo, which isn't istalled. I get this error:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

ash: sudo: not found
```

It works so far, I can login as root with the password vagrant, but I guess this is not perfect?

This is my setup: https://github.com/rubo77/ffnord-example/blob/pyddhcpd/Vagrantfile

```
  config.ssh.username = 'root'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'
  config.ssh.insert_key = 'true'
  config.ssh.shell = 'ash'
  (0..9).each do |i|
        config.vm.define "gc-node0#{i}" do |node|
        end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

By default vagrant share/sync the directory `/vagrant` (guest) with the current project directory, the one containing the `Vagrantfile` (host), more directories can be shared using `config.vm.synced_folder`, I don't know if the default `/vagrant` can be disabled.

If you aren't using the *shared directories* feature then the missing `sudo` isn't a problem.

If your filesystem is writeable you can create the `/vagrant` directory once, so on next `up` vagrant **shouldn't** try to `sudo mkdir` again;

**but** assuming you're using VirtualBox (I don't know about others emulator behavior/architecture) you'll face another problem, *shared directories* require the kernel modules `vboxsf` and `vboxguest` (from VirtualBox Guest Additions) to be built (against the running kernel sources) and loaded (insmod), and the command `mount.vboxsf` to be built and installed in `/sbin`, plus your busybox require the option *mount helpers* enabled because vagrant use `mount -t vboxsf` and not `mount.vboxsf` directly, when vagrant try to mount the shared directories and those requirements aren't matched there is a long timeout before failing with error (a minute/two or more).

Notice that busybox (current stable) support `sudo`, is just disabled by default.

If you're building the [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org) yourself from sources I can tell that the *shared* feature works (I managed to get an image with busybox to work as vagrant expect), if you're using some pre-built kernel/busybox... may be a problem, you have to find matching binaries for `vboxsf`, `vboxguest`, `mount.vboxsf` and if the *mount helpers* option is disabled in your busybox you need to find a workaround (perhaps modifying vagrant to use `mount.vboxsf`).